# How to add a write file option to argparse in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, argparse

I would like to create a very simple script that in the terminal receive two different paths(input directory and output single file). So I tried this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    p = argparse.ArgumentParser(NAME)


    p.add_argument("DIR", default=None,
        action="store", help="Inpunt corpus files")


    p.add_argument("-o", "--output",
                        help="Directs the output to a name of your choice")

    opts = p.parse_args()
    test = tuple(get_all(opts.DIR))
    with open('opts.output','w') as out:
         csv_out=opts.output.csv.writer(out, delimiter='|')

        ............
        ...more lines of code...
        ................
```

Particularly, I am having troubles with this line:

`with open('opts.output','w') as out:`

I don't know how to specify the output single file which is in `.csv format, when I test the above script in the terminal nothing happens:

```
user@MacBook-User-2:~/Projects $ python script_v1.py /Users/user/Downloads/directory -o /Users/user/Desktop/
```

Any idea of how to fix this issue?, thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an `argparse` issue; it's about calling the `csv.writer` correctly.

Look at this `csv` example (from the csv documentation page):

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

That should work if you replace 'eggs.csv' with the string in `opts.output`.  Note how the file is opened - with 'wb'.

I don't think the `FileType` helps here.  Sure it opens the file, and gives a nice `argparse` message if it can't.  But does it open the file correctly?  And that opened file can't be used in the `with` context.

And when you call this script, specify a csv file name, not just a directory.

```
-o /Users/user/Desktop/aname.csv
```

Get something like the `csv` example working, with a test file name hard coded in the script.  Once that works you can worry about getting the name from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `with open(opts.output, 'w')` instead of `with open('opts.output', 'w')`

---

Note, argparse actually has a special type for files:

```
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', type=argparse.FileType('w'),
                    default=sys.stdout)
```

In this case, the file will already be opened for you and a reasonable default of `stdout` is set:

```
opts.output.write('xyz')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I edited the status of the question. Now I got this: Traceback (most recent call last): `File "script_v1.py", line 29, in <module> with open(opts.output, 'w') as out: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found`. Any idea of why this happen?. However, I went to my Desktop and the file is actually created, but is empty.

Comment: @ml_student -- That's why I said that if you use `argparse.FileType`, the file will already be opened.  You no longer need the `with open(opts.output, 'w')` -- You can `.write` directly to `opts.output`

Comment: Maybe he needs `FileType('wb')`.